# how save image to disk

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

> I working on a mobile application, where user can upload images, am
>   using Django in server side.

I got images in two ways, I want to save the image to disk in the except case.

```
imageFile = request.FILES['image']
try:
    file_path = imageFile.temporary_file_path()
except AttributeError as e:
    logger.debug(virtualFile')
    imageStringBuffer = imageFile.read()
    virtualFile = StringIO.StringIO(imageStringBuffer)
    # want to  save the  imageStringBuffer to disk
```

> I want to to save the 'virtualFile' (in except case) to the disk , How
>   can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('imgepath', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

refer: [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/)

Comment: I've tried using this, however, the image is unable to open. Upon further investigation, the only thing being saved to the disk is the name of the uploaded file. Any suggestions?

Comment: what I used was just a sample image location,use the proper one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had been trying to get the image from the POST data, which doesn't work. A few tweaks to my form and I was able to pull it from the FILES variable. Your code worked at that point.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need `virtualFile`. You already have the image data in `imageStringBugger`. Thus:

```
with file('filename_to_save_to.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(imageStringBuffer)
```

is enough.

Comment: I got error 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte.   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Answer (score 0):

This uses the request library to get the image, open / create test.png and write the contents to it.

```
import requests
resp = requests.get('url-to-image')
f = open('test.png','w')
f.write(resp.content)
```